# OS X: Re-Sign app from .xcarchive to run it

Tags: xcode, macos, sign, xcarchive

I submitted an new version of my OS X app for review a few days ago. Now I have notices a serious bug within the app. I am 99% sure, that I have addes this bug after the app was submitted for review. Unfortionalty the bug and the submitted version are in the same git commit (created after the submit to review), so I cannot be 100% sure.

Of course I do not want to publish the app with this bug. But I do not want to wast almost a week "waiting for review" if there are other options, either.

The .xcarchive file including the uploaded version of the app are available. However I am not able to run and test this submitted version. As soon as I try to launch the app inside the .xcarchive it crashes with `EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)`.

**Is it somehow possible to (re-)sign the app file to run it?** Of course all profiles I usually use for development are available on my machine.

Comment: Did you see [iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign)

Comment: I did, but i seems only to work with iOS archive. It requires a .mobileprovision file wich is not available for OSX apps.